# libraryDependencies "org.apache.httpcomponents" not importing in built.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-httpcomponents

I add to my built.sbt: libraryDependencies += "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5.3" and i refrech sbt, but the library is not imported. anyone has any idea about this issue?

Comment: Where do you see that its not imported. What error message do you get.

Comment: in the external librairies there no librairie org.apache.httpcompnents, and when i compile my code i get the error Error:(2, 14) object mail is not a member of package javax
import javax.mail.{Authenticator, PasswordAuthentication}

Comment: You should show the full output of your build

Comment: Sounds like you might be using intellij. If so you need to reload the dependencies, it should have prompted you to do that. If not click on the SBT tab, right click the project, refresh.

Comment: If you try building from the command line with `sbt compile` what happens ?

Comment: i add  val httpcomponents="org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5.3" in Dependencies.scala, and that resolve my issue, thank you for your help